# Google Extension HostEquals for chrome.history.deleteUrl or chrome.browsingData.remove

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a chrome extension project, but cannot get host equals to work so it covers everywhere the user goes past the domain. For an example so if the user went to https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en To have the code execute again there. Is this possible to do in the background.js file? I dont think match patterns will work here.  The below code executes properly if set to an exact url chrome.history.deleteUrl({ url: 'www.google.com'} but not if I try to set it to hostEquals. I dont think this function allows hostEquals. Thank you for any help.

background.js file-

```
'use strict';

chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function() {
  }, {url: [{urlMatches : 'www.google.com'}]});

    var callback = function () {
        alert("History is clearing");
      };

    chrome.history.deleteUrl(
      { url: [{hostEquals: 'www.google.com'}]}
      , callback);
```

Is there a way I can past hostEquals in as a variable? HostEquals also does not work for chrome.browsingData.remove()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't invent nonexistent properties: as the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history#method-deleteUrl) says `deleteUrl` has only `url` property, which is "The URL to remove", not a pattern. If you want to remove all URLs from a domain then first find them using [chrome.history.search](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history#method-search). See also [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:history).

A better solution might be to use `details.url` provided to onCompleted callback as you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#property-onCompleted-callback). See also the [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:webnavigation) and look for more examples yourself.

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(details => {
  chrome.history.deleteUrl({url: details.url});
}, {url: [{hostEquals: 'www.google.com'}]});
```

Another problem in your code was that `urlMatches` is the wrong tool because it's a regular expression that can match https://foo/bar/www1google2com in irrelevant URLs.

P.S. consider using onCommitted instead of onCompleted to perform the check earlier.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: do you know why your above answer works great on some sites and others it does not work at all? When it doesn't work I get no error message or anything. For an example on the non working sites simple alert works so it is not the add listener itself, example: (chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function() {
    alert("This is my favorite website!");
}, {url: [{urlMatches : 'www.google.com'}]});) , @wOxxOm

Comment: Check `chrome://policy`, maybe you have runtime_blocked_hosts there. Otherwise try `{url: details.url.split('#')[0]}`

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it! I will try those

Comment: Unfortunately those don't appear to work, it is bizarre the code works perfectly for most sites. I am wondering if the site it is not working on has any security features to disable the function from working. - @wOxxOm

Comment: Since the event works it means the extension has full access to the URL. The only part that doesn't work is `deleteUrl` which means there is no such URL in history or something else related to history. Anyway, this is a separate thing and I can't guess what happens on your computer based on this description.

Comment: Okay thank you, If I figure it out I will write it here.

Comment: Regardless of if my chrome extension is installed I get this error when I pull up history: [Deprecation] HTML Imports is deprecated and will be removed in M80, around February 2020. Please use ES modules instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5144752345317376 and https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/07/web-components-time-to-upgrade for more details. @wOxxOm

Comment: This is unrelated.

Comment: I am a complete idiot, it works now i did not have www. in the host url i was working with thank you for all your help @wOxxOm